# Any gem similar to lockdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, lockdown

I recently migrated my app from rails 2.3.8 to rails 3.0.7, i was using lockdown for access control but lockdown is not supported in rails 3.x. Is there any gem similar to lockdown for access control, i tried cancan but its not that much effective like lockdown(i had to write if conditions since the links were still visible).

Is there any gem in rails 3 which provides similar access control

Answer (score 0):

you could take a look at gems such as *cancan* for authorization and *OmniAuth* for authentication
also look at http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=25 and http://railscasts.com/?tag_id=26 for more info.